# Rest Easy accepting only form data

Tags: web-services, rest, resteasy

I am developing rest web service using Rest Easy 3.0 and Spring. I have created 
one service like this

```
    @POST
    @Path("add-user")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String saveUser(@Form User user);
```

and this is my bean class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="user")
public class User {

    @FormParam("username")
    @XmlElement(name="username")
    String username;

    @FormParam("password")
    @XmlElement(name="password")
    String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

When I submit form it works perfectly but when I submit JSON or XML data, It does not work. But if I remove @Form annotation it works for JSON and XML but not for form.

Is there any way so that it can work for all FORM, XML and JSON?

Comment: `@Beanparam` is working only with form

Comment: You could create an additional method... Is that an option?

Comment: No, It is not an option. I just want single resource to accept all type of input.

Comment: I don't think it will be possible, unless if you write your own `MessageBodyReader`.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was useful for you. If it answers your question, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 1):

The *easy way* to achieve what you want is having different methods:

```java
@POST
@Path("add-user")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public String saveUser(User user);

@POST
@Path("add-user")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED })
public String saveUser(@FormParam("username") String username,
                       @FormParam("password") String password);
```

The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type only works with [`Form`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Form.html), [`MultivaluedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) and [`@FormParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html). Arbitraty types such as `User` only will work if you provide a custom [`MessageBodyReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) implementation.